# False display of special characters like "TM" symbol in wordpress, when cache plugin is enabled

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, utf-8, special-characters

When the WP Fastest Cache plugin is enabled it significantly improves the speed of my pages but somehow causes an error.

When I load the page the first time, the special characters like "TM" and "`" are correctly displayed. On mobile it works fine too.

However, when visiting or reloading the same page in the same browser the special characters are displayed as UTF-8 codes (as far as I know) and the "TM" symbol looks something like this: â„¢

I looked at my wp_config.php file and the charset is already UTF-8. it has something to do with the cache plugin but disabling it is not an option too since I really need the improved page speed.

Is there a way to fix the problem and let special characters display normally even after reloading the page?

Thanks in advance!
Deziox

Answer (score 0):

Update: Found the solution myself.

Just copy the following line in your .htaccess file:

AddDefaultCharset utf-8